# Flutter Equivalent useProvider in new version of Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod, hook-widgets

In previous version of `riverpod` we could use simply `useProvider()` and sending request to server without any action such as clicking on button, so in new version of `riverpod` i can't.

old version:

```dart
useEffect(() {
  myService.getService();
});

Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.white,
    child:
    useProvider(myServiceServiceProvider).when(
      idle: () {},
      loading: (){},
      success: (value){},
      error: (error, stackTrace){},
    ),
  ),
),
```

and my implementation in new version of `riverpod`:

```dart
class Home extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {

    //final future = ref.watch(dataProvider);
    useEffect(() {
      ref.read(requestProvider.notifier).send(
        method: HTTP.GET,
        endPoint: Server.$posts,
        parameters: {},
      );
      return () {};
    });

return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.white,
    //HOW CAN IMPLEMENT THIS PART TO SHOW DATA IN LISTVIEW?
  ),
),
```

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/issues/335.

Comment: @user18309290 i can't get it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ref.watch(myServiceServiceProvider).when(
      idle: () {},
      loading: (){},
      data: (value){},
      error: (error, stackTrace){},
    )
```